# Apostrophe in the surname appears as "âA" when I use Pagella font

Tags: fonts, bibtex

I use alphabetic bibliograph style. When I use default font, the following entry appears as

[O99]

```
@book{artgallery,
    author = {O’Rourke, Joseph},
    title = {{Art Gallery Theorems and Algorithms}},
    year = {1987},
    isbn = {0-19-503965-3},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press, Inc.},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
```

However, when I use Pagella i.e. add the package

```
\usepackage{tgpagella}
```

The reference appears as follows.

[OâA99]

What could be the problem with this particular font?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Proper font ecoding and input encoding loaded?

Comment: Most likely, your input document is in a Unicode format (either UTF-8 or UTF-16) but you haven't told LaTeX about that , so the input is being read "one byte at a time" and the "smart quote" apostrophe is being read as two separate 8-bit characters instead of the 16-bit code for a single character.

Comment: @samcarter Interestingly enough, I'm now trying to provide a *non-working* example. I highly doubt that it is because .bib file.

Comment: @alephzero Your comment helped me a lot. It seems that in the .bib file, I was using the apostrophe, instead of a single quote. That was causing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `.bib` file contains the wrong character (encoded as UTF-8):

```
U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
```

It should be replaced by the apostrophe (an ASCII character):

```
U+0027 APOSTROPHE
```

The fixed line:

```
author = {O'Rourke, Joseph},
```